# How do I do ConnectionPoint in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, excel, idispatch, iconnectionpoint

I'm writing a DLL which talks to Excel via its IDispatch interface. From VBA I pass in a Variant containing `Application.Caller` from which I draw the IDispatch pointer via `.pDispVal`.

What I'd like to know is how to query the interface via that IDispatch pointer. I want to set up a connection point container, and from there find a connection point to Excel. The ultimate goal is to tie things to Excel's Calculate event and be able to manipulate the Excel data.

Comment: Predominantly the Binh Ly link.

Comment: Being a bit of a Delphi newbie (in some respects) I'm still a bit in the dark, but there is a light at the end of the tunnel, and I'm fairly sure it's not the headlamp of a fast-approaching train.

Comment: Yeah, Binh's tutorials used to be the big eye opener about all things COM for me too, some eight years back...

Comment: BTW: When you're talking about "a DLL which talks to Excel" is that actually a COM server or are you somehow using exported functions that you call from VBA? I still have the feeling that you would be better off by implementing the whole thing as a regular addin, possibly dropping the VBA side.

Comment: The issue at hand is to do in Delphi what's already been done in C++ by Herbert Danler with his excelmvf add-in <http://excelmvf.sourceforge.net/>. Once you've had a look at that, tell me if you can still drop the VBA side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend Binh Ly's timelessly excellent (Delphi) COM tutorials at http://www.techvanguards.com/ which includes chapters entirely dedicated to [`IConnectionPoint` and related mechanisms](http://www.techvanguards.com/com/concepts/connectionpoints.asp).

He also offers a free tool for generating EventSink code.

Still, I have a strong feeling that this shouldn't be necessary at all if all you want to do is react to an event triggered by the Excel `Application` object. Have you tried simply using the wrapper objects that the Delphi Type Library importer generates for you? You can of course also write your own wrappers.

Then again, I haven't actually written any addins for Excel yet - but I do write addins for Outlook and Word for a living and Excel really shouldn't be much different in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Brian Long explains: http://www.blong.com/Conferences/IConUK2000/DelphiMoreAutomation/More%20Automation%20In%20Delphi.htm#Events

Other resources:

- http://dn.codegear.com/article/27126
- http://www.gtro.com/delphi/comevents_e.php

Comment: That third entry, the gtro one, covers the issue very nicely.